# Why I am getting this error: declares '<MODULE>' locally, but it is not exported

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js

I have a typescript file which exports a function to send emails using aws ses

```
//ses.tsx
let sendEmail = (args: sendmailParamsType) => {
    let params = {
    //here I get the params from args, then I send the email
    };
    return AWS_SES.sendEmail(params).promise();
};
module.exports = {
    sendEmail
};
```

then somewhere else I have a next.js API endpoint page importing the module like this

```
//index.tsx
import {sendEmail} from "../../../lib/ses";
```

the path is correct but the editor (phpstorm) highlight that line above in red and the error message is

```
declares 'sendEmail' locally, but it is not exported.
```

The path is correct and as you can see the module is exported. When I execute the page I don't get any error but the email is not sent.

Also, I use the same module from another endpoint and it works. Any suggestion to solve or debug this?

Comment: I'm not sure about module.exports, maybe it doesn't pick up on that. You could try exporting it like so: `export { sendEmail }`

Comment: We could also export the objects by assigning an object directly to module.exports     `module.exports = {sendEmail: sendEmail}`

Comment: @chriscoerdes that worked, thanks. Apparently it need to be esperted like you said if I am importing it from a .tsx file, and I also need to specify all the properties of sendmailParamsType. If I import it from a .js file, I can pass an object with some missing properties and ts does not complain, which is weird.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up ES with CommonJS.

module.exports is used with require() //CommonJS Syntax

export is used with import //ES Syntax.

you can either export all the objects at once

Oor you can simple export the object directly.

Mail.tsx:

```
export const sendEmail = () => {}
```

main.tsx

```
import {sendEmail} from "./Mail";
```

Also I recommend to use const instead of let for functions.

```
export default ...
```

also works, but may be used one time per file and can be imported with

```
import Mail from "./Mail.tsx";
Mail.sendEmail(...);
```